# I'm using mongoose-encryption and when I run my server I got the error : Authentication code missing

Tags: node.js, authentication, mongoose

I correctly setup mongoose.encryption into my code. I know that because when I go to '/register' route, my password is encrypted properly.

```
app.get('/cadastrar', (req, res) => {
 res.render('registrar');  
});

app.post('/cadastrar', (req, res) =>{
const cadastro = req.body.cadastro;
User.create({nickname: cadastro.nickname, email: cadastro.email, password: cadastro.password},(err) => {
         err ? console.log(err) : console.log('Successfully added a new user!');  res.render('/');

   });

 })
```

Below my password after registering:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5cbb2dce3014e52b34732df8"),
"nickname" : "Bulbassauro",
"email" : "bulba@pokemon.com",
"_ct" : { "$binary" : "YeLrW1jgdaT4IBFaBExr+Y4IUVkA5UtJoww6hYKqynAVg7OYjEuhJhQt2z2CtIBPHQ==", "$type" : "00" },
"_ac" : { "$binary" : "YUmRsA2QBkUw9fgyNTimqAeEPxsLgjtI4bLErh2FJmZCWyJfaWQiLCJfY3QiXQ==", "$type" : "00" },
"__v" : 0
}
```

I refactored my code, so I have a different file which I setup my mongoose.Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const encrypt  = require('mongoose-encryption');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    nickname : String,
    email    : String,
    password : String
}
);
const secret = 'viciadoemjogo';
userSchema.plugin(encrypt, {secret: secret, encryptedFields:['password']});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

And below is my route to login. But I can not log in. This means that my password is not being decrypted. 
That's when I get the error: Authentication code missing

```
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
res.render('registrar');
});

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.login.email;
    const password = req.body.login.password;

User.findOne({email: email}, (err, foundUser) =>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        if(foundUser){
            if(foundUser.password === password){
                res.render('nivelamento');
            } 
        } 
    }
});

});
```

Can anyone tell me why I can not log in?

Comment: cuz you are comparing pass-hash and pass-string

Answer (score 0):

The error is from

```
const email = req.body.login.email;
const password = req.body.login.password;
```

it should be

```
const email = req.body.email;
const password = req.body.password;
```

Once you update your code to this changes, everything will work. how mongoose encryption works is that, when you `save()` it encrypts and when you call `find()` or `findOne()` it will decrypt. So you are comparing pass-string with pass-string not pass-hash.